# What is the diference between vector socket in "set position" and "transform"

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

I am trying to apply a transformation to an object, but only depending on the index of the copy using multiply to zero index 0 results.
The editor reports an error that I am unable to understand, the following code uses "set position":
[image: With set position]
While this other one uses "transform".
[image: With Transform]

I would rather use transform because what I really need is a rotation and not a transformation. But I do not understand why the connection is failing, since both sockets seem to be of type vector.

I am using Blender 3.2.1, thanks for your time.

Comment: Simply put, `Transform` refers to the whole object or instance, and `Set Position` works on a point-by-point basis. So if you want to process certain parts of a geometry differently, you use `Set Position`.

Comment: Would it be possible to apply rotations point-by-point?

Comment: Yeah sure, I'm writing an answer to this right now....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'll try a simplified explanation here....

The difference between a circular and a diamond shaped input/output is that one is a single element, and the other is multiple elements. A diamond shaped input/output that has a point in the middle can handle both types and the node will switch automatically.

Applied to your question, this means:

- The node `Transform` transforms an object as a whole, as you know it from the *Object Mode*.
- The node `Set Position` changes single points of the object, as you know it from the *Edit Mode*.

Shown in an example, the two operations below both achieve the same result:

[image]
<sub>Here the whole object is rotated as one unit.</sub>

[image]
<sub>Here the individual points of the object are rotated.</sub>

In the case of `Set Position` you also need the information at which position the individual points are located. These values are provided by the node `Position`.

Then you can rotate them around a certain center on a certain axis using the node `Vector Rotate`.

The funny thing is, and this is where the power of this node comes in: Here you can theoretically define different values for center, axis and rotation angle for every single point in one pass. This is often used, for example, to move each point to a different position with a `Noise Texture`.

---

Referring to your screenshot, where you obviously want to rotate individual splines based on their index, you would apply the following nodes:

[image]
<sub>Here the whole object/instance is rotated as one unit.</sub>

[image]
<sub>Here the individual points of the object are rotated.</sub>

Comment: I don't know whether it falls under your 'simplified explanation' remit, but I've always thought of the distinction of 'round' v 'diamond'  sockets as  'value' v 'function-call'

Comment: @RobinBetts Well, from the programmer's point of view, in both cases a "function" is called, but both return processable values in the end. From the user's point of view, if we consider only the values returned, one returns a single value (a single vector) and the other returns multiple values (an array of vectors).

Comment: This has been a beautifully developed answer, many thanks for your time

Comment: @LuisAyuso Thanks ;-) ...you're welcome!